# SSRS error- The variable name @PhoneNo has already been declared. Variables names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: reporting-services

I have removed declaring the parameters which are used in the where clause, then the parameters were automatically generated which is good, but there is one parameter @Type is used for IF condition in the code like below. I have declared @Type variable , still I don't see that parameter generated. Can I know how does this work in SSRS please.

declare @Type Varchar(max)

if @Type = '1234'
begin
set @Type = null

select....

END

else if @Type != '1234'
begin 
select.....

END

Comment: show the code that you are using for your dataset. Or delete the parameter.. refresh your dataset that has the parameter.. it should put the parameter back in.. else you can add it in manually.

Comment: thanks for the response Harry, I have edited the question. Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: If the first issue was fixed then you should start a new question. If it was not then you should try to avoid changing the question as the title now has no bearing to the actual question now.

Comment: If a parameter is declared and set within the code, it will not show up as a required parameter in SSRS. As Alan mentioned.. please do not change question once answered as SO is not just for you, but also for others like you looking to solve similar questions. The answers for questions will make no sense and will be confusing to anyone reading or trying to figure out what's going on!

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly because you have not been consistent with the case of the variable. SSRS is case sensitive when it comes to these things.

So if you have something like

```
DECLARE @PhoneNo varchar(10)
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE PhoneNo = @phoneno
```

This will fail because SSRS sees `@phoneno` as a different variable to `@PhoneNo`

Make sure eveywhere you use it, the case is the same.

Comment: thanks for the response Alan, I have edited the question. Can you please let me know how to fix this?